# Update trigger not working correctly

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables abstractDetails and auditAbstractDetails. I have a web form from where a person submits details about abstract (title, background, objective etc.) and it inserts value into abstractDetails table.

Now I have written a trigger so whenever a person updates his Form and submit it again, it should populate new values into abstractDetails as well as it should populate old values and New values in the AuditabstractDetails table               ( title,background,objective..... auditTitle,auditBackground.....)

old value should store in AuditabstractDetails tables under the columns title, background etc. and new values will be stored under the columns auditTitle,auditBackground etc.)

here is my trigger:

```
USE [Abstract]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trgAuditabstractDetails]    Script Date: 09/28/2016 11:45:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAuditabstractDetails] 
ON [dbo].[abstractDetails] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON
  delete from AuditabstractDetails where Id IN (SELECT I.Id
  FROM Inserted I);
  insert into  AuditabstractDetails(Id, abstractInfoId, title, background, 
  objective, design, result, Audittitle, Auditbackground, 
  Auditobjective, Auditdesign, Auditresult) 
  -- case 1: ID unchanged
  SELECT I.Id, I.abstractInfoId, D.title, D.background, D.objective, 
  D.design, D.result,
  I.title, I.background, I.objective, I.design, I.result
  FROM Inserted I
  JOIN Deleted D on I.Id=D.Id;
END
GO
```

after this when I am updating the value of form (title, background etc.) in the abstractDetails table from the backend (from DB by editing the value in abstractDetails  table), it is working perfect. But when I am updating it through the form and submitting it, It is updating New values in both columns ( title, auditTitle etc..), It is not storing old values in specific columns , instead it is storing new values in both the columns.

```
abstractDetails table
===========================================
Id |title | background | Result
-------------------------------------------
1    Abs1    backAbs2     resAbs2
2    Abs2    backAbs2     resAbs2
-------------------------------------------

Expected Result:

AuditabstractDetails table
===============================================
Id |title | background | Result | AuditTitle  | auditBackground |auditResult
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Abs1    backAbs2    resAbs2    Audit1        auditback1     auditres1
2    Abs2    backAbs2    resAbs2    Audit2        auditback2     auditres2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ActualResult:

AuditabstractDetails table
===============================================
Id |title | background | Result | AuditTitle  | auditBackground |auditResult
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Audit1  auditback1  auditres1   Audit1      auditback1      auditres1
2    Audit2  auditback2  auditres2   Audit2      auditback2      auditres2
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Need help

Comment: Your trigger deletes inserted values and does the same again and it only works only for updated part,that too when only single value is returned from inserted..please update question with what is the end result for inserted,updated part

Comment: I have removed the Inserted part

Comment: Your delete statement will fail when Inserted contains more than 1 row. You should change that to IN or a join.

Comment: did that, but the problem is still there..I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem isn't with the trigger, but is with whatever's saving your data.  If it works as desired from SQL Server but fails when the UI is making the call, then you need to check the UI to see what's going on.  It seems likely that the UI is updating the record more than once.  I would test this by removing the `delete` portion of your trigger and seeing how many rows you end up with in your audit table.